# When I grant storage or file/media permissions on Android 8, what folders are accessible by the app?

Tags: android

When I grant storage or file/media permissions on Android 8, what folders are accessible by the app?

I searched online but I couldn't find any clear answer

Answer (score 0):

It should be anything under `/sdcard/` (internal storage) and your actual SD card if you have one.

That means Downloads, Pictures, Music, Documents, etc. However, it doesn't grant the app access to any other app's data, as that's stored under `/data/data/` (`/sdcard/` is a symlink to `/data/media/0/`).

It's a pretty powerful permission, but if you're worried about security, it's a better idea to encrypt your private stuff or keep it in the cloud, than to avoid any apps requesting `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: So basically will get access to my sd card fully or just all folders except data? Also there is any way to just give permissions to one folder or more than one folder instead of all my storage?

Comment: @Totty.js It will have access to anything under Internal Storage or External Storage. That isn't where apps keep their private data, although it is where Downloads and Documents are located.